# Give spacing between text and radio in ASP

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

How can I give spacing between Radio Button and Text using Asp:RadioButton control in ASP.NET?

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio1" runat="server" GroupName="Group1" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio1" CssClass="Space" runat="server" GroupName="Group1" />
```

and CSS:

```
.Space label
{
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

works here...

Answer (score 7):

Use CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] 
{
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Or:

```
input[type="radio"] + label
{
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method that works is to precede the text property of the radiobutton with the &nbsp; symbol like this Text="&nbsp; I have pad before me"

Comment: That works perfectly! Also, the semicolon and the space after it aren't necessary, just put `&nbsp` where you want it and there it will be!

Answer (score 1):

where is your text? use a label for the radiobutton or put some margin in CSS around the button.

Comment: seem to be using MVC for too long :) the answer is css anyway :)